# É possivel criar um script que simule pressionar as teclas CTRL e + ou CTRL e -?

Tags: javascript, teclado, acessibilidade, resolução-de-tela, zoom

Resolver problema de acessibilidade numa pagina.
É possivel simular num script as teclas <kbd>CRL</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd> e <kbd>CTR</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd>.
Estas teclas pressionadas aumentam e diminuem o zoom da tela, respectivamente.
Complementando minha pergunta, uma das formas de melhorar acessibilidade na pagina seria o de ampliar/diminuir a pagina, recursos  esses que essa sequencia de teclas fonece.

Comment: [Relacionado](https://qastack.com.br/programming/1055336/changing-the-browser-zoom-level) Pelo que pesquisei, não é possível diretamente, somente via CSS, mas não sei o seu contexto porque faltou detalhes na pergunta.

Comment: Se a ideia é simular apenas, então a propriedade `transform: scale(<valor desejado>%)` no elemento `body {}` deve resolver. Mas sem apresentar argumentos para a necessidade, então talvez seja um problema XY e não temos como ajudar com a pergunta na forma atual... Outra coisa, usou a tag [tag:acessibilidade] na pergunta, e essa tag é muito especifica, mas você não explicou aonde a sua necessidade sem encaixa em acessibilidade, é importante [edit] e explicar todos os pontos e/ou necessidade de forma clara. Obrigado por compreender.